# How to generate allure reports directly into a dashboard instead of generating them locally?

Tags: appium, appium-android, allure, test-reporting

I am working with Appium, and I am exploring test reporting tools to integrate them with my project.

Allure report seems to be a good fit for some reasons, but my problem is that allure reports are being generated locally and disappear on every new test execution.

I want to have logs of my test reports and to be able to access old reports whenever I want, something like Cypress Dashboard.

I wonder if there's an allure dashboard like this https://presidenten.github.io/wdio-video-reporter-example-report/#. My vision is to integrate my android test cases with Bitbucket pipelines and have a look at the results, failed test cases, and videos after successful execution.

If not, is there any other test reporting tool that can be integrated with appium and supports what I have talked about above?